# Idea regarding sudo su - user - in jsch

Tags: java, shell, sudo, jsch

I am having problems with using sudo su in jsch, below is my post(exec.java):

```
package com.test;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Exec{
  public static void main(String[] arg){
    try{
      JSch jsch=new JSch();  

      String host=null;
      if(arg.length>0){
        host=arg[0];
      }
      else{
        host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                                         "username"+
                                         "@hostName"); 
      }
      String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
      host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

      Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

      /*
      String xhost="127.0.0.1";
      int xport=0;
      String display=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter display name", 
                                                 xhost+":"+xport);
      xhost=display.substring(0, display.indexOf(':'));
      xport=Integer.parseInt(display.substring(display.indexOf(':')+1));
      session.setX11Host(xhost);
      session.setX11Port(xport+6000);
      */

      // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
      UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
      session.setUserInfo(ui);
      session.connect();
      String command = "cd bin";

      System.out.println(command);
      Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
      channel.setInputStream(null);
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

      InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

      channel.connect();
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("sudo su - user -");

      byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
      while(true){
        while(in.available()>0){
          int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
          if(i<0)break;
          System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));

        }
        if(channel.isClosed()){
          System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
          break;
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        System.out.println("te");
      }

      channel.disconnect();
      session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){ return passwd; }
    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
      Object[] options={ "yes", "no" };
      int foo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
             str,
             "Warning", 
             JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
             JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
             null, options, options[0]);
       return foo==0;
    }

    String passwd;
    JTextField passwordField=(JTextField)new JPasswordField(20);

    public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return true; }
    public boolean promptPassword(String message){
      Object[] ob={passwordField}; 
      int result=
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, message,
                                      JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        passwd=passwordField.getText();
        return true;
      }
      else{ 
        return false; 
      }
    }
    public void showMessage(String message){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }
    final GridBagConstraints gbc = 
      new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1,1,
                             GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                             GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                             new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0);
    private Container panel;
    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                              String name,
                                              String instruction,
                                              String[] prompt,
                                              boolean[] echo){
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      panel.add(new JLabel(instruction), gbc);
      gbc.gridy++;

      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

      JTextField[] texts=new JTextField[prompt.length];
      for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        panel.add(new JLabel(prompt[i]),gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        if(echo[i]){
          texts[i]=new JTextField(20);
        }
        else{
          texts[i]=new JPasswordField(20);
        }
        panel.add(texts[i], gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
      }

      if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, 
                                       destination+": "+name,
                                       JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
         ==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        String[] response=new String[prompt.length];
        for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
          response[i]=texts[i].getText();
        }
    return response;
      }
      else{
        return null;  // cancel
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Normal sudo su is good but I want to run multiple commands after sudo su, some of the points which might be informative.

1. login to server and sudo with user
2. sudo su - user - is without password
3. perform some commands

regards,

icr

Comment: _I am having problems with using sudo su in jsch_ 

what problems?

Comment: Hi, I am not able to run multiple commands after using sudo su - username -, I tried using Sudo.java in jsch but still its not working.

Comment: are you getting an exception? then please post the stacktrace

Comment: Hi, I didn't get any exception. once I hit the command sudo su - user -; ls -lrt and then it doesn't do anything except executing the sudo command, i.e. ls -lrt is not executed.

Comment: @icr: How you sloved this problem , am too struckup here.

Answer (score 1):

second way is that you need to redirect providing second password.

Try to use `sudo -S -p`.

In the past I had the same problem but solved. To save your time here is my code:

**SudoExec class**

```
public abstract class SudoExec {

private String mHost;
private static String passwd;
private SSHObserverItf mObserver = null;
protected boolean isForceStop = false;
protected boolean isAsIs = false;
protected Timer mTimer = null;



//default constructor
public SudoExec(String hostName,String userName,String password){
    setHost(userName+"@"+hostName);
    setPassword(password);
}

public void init(int timeToWait) {

    mTimer = new Timer();


    new Thread(){       
        public  void run(){
            execCMD();
        }           
    }.start();

    mTimer.doWait(timeToWait);

    isForceStop = true;
}


private void execCMD (){

    isForceStop = false;        

    try{
        JSch jsch=new JSch();  

        String host=getHost();


        String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
        host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

        Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);



        // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
        UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
        session.setUserInfo(ui);
        session.connect();

        String command=getCmd();

        Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");

        ((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);

        if(isAsIs == true){
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
            }
        else{
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("sudo -S -p '' " + command);
        }

        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
          OutputStream out=channel.getOutputStream();
          ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

          channel.connect();

          out.write((passwd+"\n").getBytes());
          out.flush();

        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while( isForceStop == false ){              
            while(in.available()>0 ){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;

                mObserver.onResponse((new String(tmp, 0, i)));

            }
            if(channel.isClosed()){
                mObserver.onResponse("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                mTimer.doNotify();
                break;
            }


            try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }

        mObserver.onResponse("close channel ... ");         
        channel.disconnect();
        mObserver.onResponse("close session ... ");
        session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        mObserver.onErrorResponse(e.getMessage());
    }



}



public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){
        return passwd;
    }

    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
        return true;
    }



    public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return true; }
    public boolean promptPassword(String message){
        return true;
    }

    public void showMessage(String message){
    }

    @Override
    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String arg0, String arg1,
            String arg2, String[] arg3, boolean[] arg4) {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setPassword(String password){
    passwd=password;
}

public void setHost(String hostname){
    mHost=hostname;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return passwd;
}


public String getHost(){
    return mHost;
}

protected abstract String getCmd();

public void setObserver(SSHObserverItf observer) {
    mObserver = observer;
}   
}
```

**SSHObserverItf interface**

```
public interface SSHObserverItf {
public void onResponse(String line);
public void onErrorResponse(String line);
}
```

**SomeTask**

```
public class SomeTask extends SudoExec implements SSHObserverItf{

private static String command = "";
private static String hostname = "";
private static String user = "";
private static String pass = "";
private static Boolean isError=false;

private static String wait = "300";



static public void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ParseException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {


    new SomeTask(hostname,user,pass);

    if (isError == true){
        System.out.println("Test failed");
    }   
    else{
        System.out.println("\nSucceeded to invoke command : " + command);
    }   

}



public CopyPeriodMergeToExternal(String hostName, String userName, String password) throws IOException, ParseException {

    super(hostName, userName, password);

    SSHObserverItf observer = this;

    super.setObserver(observer);

    super.init(Integer.parseInt(wait) * 1000);

}




@Override
protected String getCmd() {

    isAsIs = true;


    command="rm -f somescript.sh";


    System.out.println("Run followed command : " + command);

    return command;
}

@Override
public void onResponse(String line) {
    System.out.println(line);       
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(String line) {
    System.out.println(line);
    System.out.println("Error has occured");        
    isError = true;
}
}
```

The main part in `SudoExec` class  is:

```
public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){ //     <---
        return passwd;
    }

    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
        return true;  //     <---
    }
```

Hope it will solve your problem

**[EDIT]**

After you got first response, you close the session.

Therefore next command starts as not super user.

My suggestion is to do not create session but run each command with `sudo` preffix

Comment: Sure, when you run `su` aka superuser you must provide password once more, right?

Comment: Yeah, but in my case it doesn't require password. :(

Comment: Hi, its ask for password and I am not having any password or how is the prefix added?

Comment: i was just wondering about the statement: while(true && isForceStop == false)                                  Wouldn't it be simpler to just write: while( !isForceStop)  ?

Answer (score 1):

I also have to ssh on a remote server, then sudo with diffrent user and finally execute a command, what I did is:

```
package oracle.idaas.changelog.util;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class Test {
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        String user = "opc";
        String host = "101.252.109.112";
        String password = "NotMyPassword"
        int port = 22;

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        System.out.println("session created.");
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();

        ChannelExec channel=(ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
        channel.setCommand("sudo su - oracle -c \"pwd\";");
        channel.connect();

        String msg=null;
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        while((msg=in.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(msg);
            lines.add(msg);
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    } catch(Exception e){
        logger.fatal("Remote BTU Process FAILED" + e);
    }
}

}
```

If you see **sudo su - oracle -c "your-command"** will solve your problem.