# jsch multiple command using sudo

Tags: java, ssh, sudo, jsch, apache-commons-net

need to login with my id, execute below command

1. sudo su - tstusr
2. execute the script   :  ./app/t1.sh status

   ```
      String sudoCommand ="sudo su - tstusr";
      List commands = new ArrayList();
      commands.add("./app/t1.sh status")
       try {
       channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
       channel.setPty(true);

       channel.setCommand(sudoCommand);
       channel.connect();
       List<String> resultString = null;
       for (String command : commands) {
           result = new ArrayList<>();
           OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
           InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
           InputStream err = channel.getErrStream();
           out.write((command.concat("\n")).getBytes());
           out.flush();
           resultString = readStream(channel, in, true);
           LOGGER.debug("execute command {} o/p  {} ",commands, resultString);
           result.addAll(resultString);
       }

   } finally {
       if (channel != null) {
           channel.disconnect();
       }

   }
   ```

When executed hangs there with /app/t1.sh : no File or directory .
The mentioned file is available and owned by "tstusr" and seems the setcommand does not complete the sudo su - command which is causing the error.

ouput :

```
20:28:13.492 INFO  o.t.u.r.repoImpl- Output stream execution ./app/t1.sh start
-bash: ./app/t1.sh: No such file or directory
[tstusr@hosrtch102 ~]$
```

@update 
Also this error i could see only when in debug mode and keep this debugger after channel.connect() line . which means internally it needs bit of delay seems

I tried by removing . infront of script from "./app/t1.sh" to "/app/t1.sh", it worked not,But as mentioned it is working fine in debug mode of java where there is the delay ,should i add thread wait after "channel.connect"

1) Should I add delay after channel.connect()
2) after sudo command added in set command ,should I check for exit  status or out stream and then feed the second command in out stream

Comment: Does the `sudo su - tstusr` asks password?

Comment: it does not my user has sudo access to tstusr

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18534922/584420

Comment: with removing dot in front of script it works but, it as mentioned in works in debug mode of eclipse where there is delay in execution as in manual debug. Should i need to add thread wait?